# Problemas com autoload

Tags: php

estou iniciando uma aplicação aplicando mvc. criei o composer.json com os seguintes parametros de autoload:

```
    "autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "SOCIAL\\":"vendor/SOCIAL/",
        "App\\":"App/",
        "Predis\\": "src/" 
        }
```

tenho na public o index que chama a route o seguinte trecho:

```
require_once "../vendor/autoload.php";

if ( isset($_SESSION['id_user']) )
{
    $route = new \App\Route;
}
else
{
    header('location:'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/login.php');
}
```

tenho na minha classe de rota o seguinte:

```
namespace App;

class Route
{
    private $routes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->initRoutes();
        $this->run($this->getUrl());

    }

    public function initRoutes()
    {
        $routes['home'] = array('route'=>'/','controller'=>'indexController','action'=>'index');
        $routes['login'] = array('route'=>'/login','controller'=>'indexController','action'=>'login');
        $this->setRoutes($routes);

    }

    public function setRoutes(array $routes)
    {
        $this->routes = $routes;

    }

    public function run($url)
    {
        array_walk($this->routes, function($route) use ($url)
            {
                if ( $url == $route['route'])
                {
                    $class = "App\\Controller\\".ucfirst($route['controller']);
                    $controller = new $class.'()';
                    $action = $route['action'];
                    $controller->$action();
                }
            });
    }

    public function getUrl()
    {
        return parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH);
    }
}
```

e dentro de App\Controllers\IndexController.php

```
namespace App\Controller;

class IndexController
{

    public function index()
    {
        echo "Route / Controller : Index";
    }

    public function login()
    {
        echo "Route / Controller : login";


    }
```

recebo o erro

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\IndexController' not found in /var/www/new/App/Route.php on line 36
```

Comment: onde está a implementação do autoload?

Comment: esta no index que chama o controller.

Comment: adicione-o na pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Falta a contra-barra antes do `"App\\Controller\\"`.

```
$class = "\\App\\Controller\\".ucfirst($route['controller']);
```